# Does derby support replace into of mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, unit-testing, derby

Does derby support REPLACE INTO of mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby doesn't have any REPLACE [statement](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/crefsqlj39374.html) and no equivalent AFAIK.